# Solving for Lagrangian multipliers with additional assumptions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint, lagrange-multiplier

I want to solve the Lagrangian with two multipliers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, but with an additional convexity assumption. However, when I solve it case by case under such an assumption, I get 0 as the solution, and that is definitely not correct.

It would be great if I can get $(a, T, \lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ independent solutions for each of the variables.

```
f1 = γ*(T - a - (1 - B) K)/(c_F - c_S);
f2 = ((K - T)/(c_S) - (T - a - (1 - B) K)/(c_F - c_S));
g1 = (T - a - (1 - B) K);
g2 = ((K - T - (-a + K*B) c_S/c_F));

L[T_, a_, λ1_, λ2_] = a*γ*(T - a - (1 - B) K)/(c_F - c_S) - 
   T*((K - T)/(c_S) - (T - a - (1 - B) K)/(c_F - c_S)) + λ1*g1 + λ2*g2;

(* Solve for case 1: λ1==0, λ2==0 *)
Assuming[(4 γ*c_F) - c_s*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0, 
 Solve[{D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], a] == 0, 
   D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], T] == 0, g1 == 0, 
   g2 == 0, λ1 == 0, λ2 == 0}, {a, T, λ1, λ2}]]

(* Solve for case 2: λ1==0, λ2>=0 *)
Assuming[(4 γ*c_F) - c_s*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0, 
 Solve[{D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], a] == 0, 
   D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], T] == 0, g1 == 0, 
   g2 == 0, λ1 == 0, λ2 > 0}, {a, T, λ1, λ2}]]

(* Solve for case 3: λ1>=0, λ2==0 *)
Assuming[(4 γ*c_F) - c_s*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0, 
 Solve[{D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], a] == 0, 
   D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], T] == 0, g1 == 0, 
   g2 == 0, λ1 > 0, λ2 == 0}, {a, T, λ1, λ2}]]

(* Solve for case 4: λ1>0, λ2>0 *)
Assuming[(4 γ*c_F) - c_s*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0, 
 Solve[{D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], a] == 0, 
   D[L[a, T, λ1, λ2], T] == 0, g1 == 0, 
   g2 == 0, λ1 > 0, λ2 > 0}, {a, T, λ1, λ2}]]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can't use underscores in your variable names: they are reserved for the `Blank` pattern in Mathematica expressions. Remove the underscores instead (e.g. use `cF` instead of `c_F`). As a general best practice, you should also avoid single-letter uppercase variable names, as many of those are reserved internally (e.g. `K` in your code).

Comment: Once you do that, the very first case, of both multipliers being zero, returns two solutions, one of which has non-zero values for the parameters. I didn't wait for the other ones, as they seem to take a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = γ*(T - a - (1 - B) K)/(cF - cS);
f2 = ((K - T)/(cS) - (T - a - (1 - B) K)/(cF - cS));
g1 = (T - a - (1 - B) K);
g2 = ((K - T - (-a + K*B) cS/cF));
L = a*f1 - T*f2 + λ1*g1 + λ2*g2;
```

the general case:

```
Solve[{Grad[L, {a, T}] == 0, g1 == 0, g2 == 0}, {a,T, λ1, λ2}, 
 Assumptions -> (4 γ*cF) - cs*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0]
{{a -> B K, T -> K, λ1 -> -((B K γ)/(cF - cS)), λ2 -> (cF K)/((cF - cS) cS)}}
```

λ1 =0  and λ2 =0:

```
Solve[{Grad[a*f1 - T*f2, {a, T}] == 0}, {a, T}, Assumptions -> (4 γ*cF) - cs*(1 + γ)^2 >= 0] // Simplify

{{a -> -((K (B cS (-1 + γ) + cF (1 + γ - 2 B γ)))/(cS (-1 + γ)^2 + 4 cF γ)),
  T -> -((K γ (-2 cF + cS (1 + B - γ + B γ)))/(cS (-1 + γ)^2 + 4 cF γ))}}
```

The next cases are yours.